# How can I dispatch Python 2 functions based on the data type passed to the function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, generic-function, single-dispatch

I would like to dispatch Python functions dependent (e.g. using a [dict approach](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-2nd/0596007973/ch04s17.html)) on the data type of the argument passed to the "dispatching" function (e.g. using `isinstance()`). Are there implementation alternatives? What's the easiest approach?

Comment: Did you try using the dictionary approach? What happened?

Comment: I *strongly* urge you to consider upgrading to Python 3, at which point the standard library offers you the [`@singledispatch` decorator function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) to take care of type-based dispatching.

Comment: I know. But I have to use python-2.7 explicitly here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of Python 3.4, the Python standard library includes support for [`@singledispatch()` generic functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch).

This lets you register multiple functions to handle different types, and it'll handle dispatch based on type, including subclass testing and caching. The method is described in [PEP 443 - *Single-dispatch generic functions*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0443/).

There is a [backport available on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/singledispatch/) that supports Python 2.6 and up, written by the PEP author.

Note that Python 2.7 will soon be hitting a final end-of-life date, where it'll no longer receive bug fixes and security updates; you really need to plan for upgrading to Python 3 sooner rather than later. When you do, you'll note that the Python 3.7 version supports using type hinting to document what type each function accepts.

For example, a series of functions to remove `None` and `False` values from a nested dictionary-and-list data structure (a typical JSON data structure), can be defined as:

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def remove_null_false(ob):
    return ob

@remove_null_false.register
def _process_list(ob: list):
    return [remove_null_false(v) for v in ob]

@remove_null_false.register
def _process_list(ob: dict):
    return {k: remove_null_false(v) for k, v in ob.items()
            if v is not None and v is not True and v is not False}
```

In Python versions < 3.7 you'd have to move the type to the `@remove_null_false.register(...)` decorator factory notation.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the below example.

```
def get_int_square(a):
    """
    Returns square of integer parameter
    """
    return a ** 2

def get_float_cube(a):
    """
    Returns cube of float parameter
    """
    return a ** 3

def sum_of_items(l):
    """
    Returns sum of all the items in list
    """
    return sum(l)

def get_squared_items(t):
    return tuple(item ** 2 for item in t)

def dispatching(a):
    """
    Calls the corresponding functions based on match found in the dictionary
    """
    functions = {
        'int': get_int_square,
        'float': get_float_cube,
        'list': sum_of_items,
        'tuple': get_squared_items
    }

    data_type = str(type(a)).split("'")[1]
    result = functions[data_type](a)
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(dispatching(12))  # 144
    print(dispatching(1.2)) # 1.7279999999999998
    print(dispatching((4, 7, 9, 3, 1, 5, 8))) # (16, 49, 81, 9, 1, 25, 64)
    print(dispatching([56, 4, 50, 26, 24]))   # 160
```

Comment: Using own types instead of int, float, etc. should not be an issue. Cool. Thx.

Comment: You can use other types also, you just need to add more code lines. Please comment if you got any issue. Thanks for your reply.